# Firebase authentication using Twitter login on iOS now Twitter Kit is no longer supported

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitterkit

I would like to authenticate my Firebase app using Twitter logins. The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login?authuser=0) states to use Twitter Kit however Twitter stopped supporting Twitter Kit in 2018.

What is the recommended way to integrate Twitter logins into Firebase going forward?

Comment: There is no official solution right now but the Firebase team is working on it see https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/firebase-talk/KeqfIqZmBag for more information.